# How to get past 5 events from now using Google calendar API?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

I want to fetch last 5 events (counting recurring ones) sorted by event `start` time (descending order) from Google calendar API but there seems to be no way. These events should be related to the time I make the request i.e. past 5 events from now.

Below code returns least recent 5 events but I want the most recent events:

```
const resFromApi = await calendar.events.list({
      calendarId: "primary",
      oauth_token: token,
      orderBy: "startTime",
      singleEvents: true,
      maxResults: 5,
    });
```

api reference: https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list
sdk: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node

Answer (score 3):

### Answer

*It is not possible to list events in descending order*

### Work-around

- Use the query parameters `timeMax` with the date of today (`2021-06-28T00:00:00.000Z`). It must be an RFC3339 timestamp.
- Once you get all the events, take the last 5 events.
- *(optional):* use the query parameter `timeMin` if you have an approximate idea of the date

### Feature request

Google has a tool called [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) to track bugs and feature requests during product development. Currently there is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/36761674) requesting to be able to list events in descending order. You can click on the star to prioritize the case and receive notifications when they occur.

### References

- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list)
- [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)